# Prevent concurrent Controller requests from an user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a Controller action in my ASP.Net MVC project, which should not be allowed to execute concurrently by the same user.
When an user submits Request #1 and during Request #1 is still running all other Requests should be rejected. This logic must be based on the user.

**I wrote some code and I think it could work**

As I have issues with testing on localhost and it is a sensitive part of my website, I would really appreciate if you could review the code and give me some feedback!

## UPDATE

I published the code below into production and I had one time the case that an user created a lock and didn't unlock. I don't know where is the issue.

## Controller

```
public class LockTestController : Controller
    {
        public string Submit(int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                if (TransactionLockRepository.HasLock(userId))
                    return DateTime.Now + $"Err: UserId {userId} already requested already ";

                //todo: do important stuff an user should not execute concurrently

                TransactionLockRepository.RemoveLock(userId);
                return DateTime.Now + " Submit successfully. UserId: " + userId + " ";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TransactionLockRepository.RemoveLock(userId);
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
                return  DateTime.Now + " Error " + e;
            }
        }
    }
```

## LockRepository

```
public static class TransactionLockRepository
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentBag<int> UserLocks = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        private static readonly object _lockInsert = new object();
        private static readonly object _lockRemove = new object();

        public static bool HasLock(int userId)
        {
            lock (_lockInsert)
            {
                var i = userId;
                var hasLock = UserLocks.TryPeek(out i);
                if (hasLock)
                    return true;
                UserLocks.Add(userId);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool RemoveLock(int userId)
        {
            lock (_lockRemove)
            {
                var i = userId;
                UserLocks.TryTake(out i);
                return i == userId;
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect that the requests get only blocked when the userId is in the Lock Repo. Other users should not be affected

Comment: I have implemented the suggestion from @Abdullah Dibas comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that will work all the time. What if two action requests call `HasLock` method at the same time? and the two requests sequentially sets the variable `hasLock` to false before executing the code line `UserLocks.Add(userId);`.
You may need in this case to use lock inside HasLock method:

```
private static object _lockObj = new object();
public static bool HasLock(int userId)
{
   lock(_lockObj)    
   {
     var i = userId;
     var hasLock = UserLocks.TryPeek(out i);
     if (hasLock)
         return true;
     UserLocks.Add(userId);
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Good point. I should also add a lock() in the RemoveLock method then, right? When TryTake(out userId) fails, the user can never call the Action again

Comment: I don't think you need to add a lock inside the Remove method, since if you lock HasLock method then only one action request will pass and only that request will call RemoveLock method, in other words no concurrent requests will call the Remove method.

Comment: I added the lock() to the repository and released it. 
Unfortunately it happened, that an user has an active lock for hours and it didn't get unlocked. I am really confused how that can happen. I remove the lock in the catch and also before i return something when there is no exception. The unlock method should be definitly reached. The code is the same like in my initial post (plus the lock() you suggested)

Comment: This will work until your app is running on redundant servers, like a farm. You may need to set your flag in a database using transactions to mitigate races.